# upgrading AWS Cli in RHEL servers

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, rhel

aws-cli/1.16.280 Python/2.7.5 Linux/3.10.0-1160.92.1.el7.x86_64 botocore/1.13.16 /usr/local/bin/aws -> /usr/local/aws/bin/aws above is the version before upgrading.

after upgrading it shows as
aws-cli/2.9.16 Python/3.9.11 Linux/3.10.0-1160.92.1.el7.x86_64 exe/x86_64.rhel.7 prompt/off /usr/local/bin/aws -> /usr/local/aws-cli/v2/current/bin/aws

1.what is prompt/off at the end means ??

2.while upgrading , i changed the install directory . will that be a problem ? or should i keep the install directory same as old version ?

3.does aws cli upgrade needs a restart ??

Answer (score 0):

When updating the `v2` version of `aws-cli` the old versions are maintained, as the idea was that you may want to use a previous version of the AWS CLI v2 without having to reinstall, as we can read in this [issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/5979).

If you do not want to keep the old version you can follow the following doc page [AWS CLI version 2 migration instructions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cliv2-migration-instructions.html) to understand more how remove the old one.

Where probably you will need to uninstall the v1 using pip:

```
pip3 uninstall awscli
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. 

how do i find whether i got both versions of aws cli (1 & 2) installed or not ??